# Partial cartesian product (ensure one value in each set)

Tags: ruby, cartesian-product

Given a set of items `[z,a,b,c]` I want to find the "cartesian power" (cartesian product with itself *n* times) but **only those results that have a `z` in them**. For example:

```
normal_values = ["a","b","c"]
p limited_cartesian( normal_values, "z", 2 )
#=> [
#=>   ["z", "z"]
#=>   ["z", "a"]
#=>   ["z", "b"]
#=>   ["z", "c"]
#=>   ["a", "z"]
#=>   ["b", "z"]
#=>   ["c", "z"]
#=> ]
```

I can do this by spinning through the full set and skipping entries that don't have the special value, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way. Preferably one that allows me to only evaluate the desired entries lazily, without wasting time calculating unwanted entries.

```
def limited_cartesian( values, special, power )
  [special, *values].repeated_permutation(power)
                    .select{ |prod| prod.include?( special ) }
end
```

Comment: Is `'z'` supposed to be in `normal_values`?

Comment: @mu It could be if you want it there; I pulled it out because it is treated specially, and in my actual code it's something that I am injecting into an array of not normal values.

Comment: `limited_cartesian( normal_values, "z", 3 ).size => 37`!! You are probably aware (from an answer to the related question you asked recently) that the first two lines of `limited_cartesian` above can be replaced with `toomany = [special, *values].repeated_permutation(power)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: With v3.0 I finally have something respectable.  As is oft the case, the key was looking at the problem the right way.  It occurred to me that I could repeatedly permute `normal_values << special`, `power - 1` times, then for each of those permutations, there would be one more element to add.  If the permutation contained at least one `special`, any element of `normal_values << special` could be added; otherwise, `special` must be added.

```
def limited_cartesian( values, special, power )
  all_vals = values + [special]
  all_vals.repeated_permutation(power-1).map do |p|
    if p.include?(special)
      *all_vals.each_with_object([]) { |v,a| a << (p + [v]) }
    else
      p + [special]
    end
  end       
end

limited_cartesian( values, 'z', 1 )
  # [["z"]]

limited_cartesian( values, 'z', 2 )
  # => [["a", "z"], ["b", "z"], ["c", "z"],
  #     ["z", "a"], ["z", "b"], ["z", "c"],
  #     ["z", "z"]] 

limited_cartesian( values, 'z', 3 )
  # => [["a", "a", "z"], ["a", "b", "z"], ["a", "c", "z"],
  #     ["a", "z", "a"], ["a", "z", "b"], ["a", "z", "c"],
  #     ["a", "z", "z"], ["b", "a", "z"], ["b", "b", "z"],
  #     ["b", "c", "z"], ["b", "z", "a"], ["b", "z", "b"],
  #     ["b", "z", "c"], ["b", "z", "z"], ["c", "a", "z"],
  #     ["c", "b", "z"], ["c", "c", "z"], ["c", "z", "a"],
  #     ["c", "z", "b"], ["c", "z", "c"], ["c", "z", "z"],
  #     ["z", "a", "a"], ["z", "a", "b"], ["z", "a", "c"],
  #     ["z", "a", "z"], ["z", "b", "a"], ["z", "b", "b"],
  #     ["z", "b", "c"], ["z", "b", "z"], ["z", "c", "a"],
  #     ["z", "c", "b"], ["z", "c", "c"], ["z", "c", "z"],
  #     ["z", "z", "a"], ["z", "z", "b"], ["z", "z", "c"],
  #     ["z", "z", "z"]]
```

This is my v2.1, which works, but is not pretty.  I'll leave it for the record.

```
def limited_cartesian( values, special, power )
  ndx = Array(0...power)
  ndx[1..-1].each_with_object( [[special]*power] ) do |i,a|
    ndx.combination(i).to_a.product(values.repeated_permutation(power-i).to_a)
       .each { |pos, val| a << stuff_special(special, pos, val.dup) }
  end
end

def stuff_special( special, pos, vals )
  pos.each_with_object(Array.new(pos.size + vals.size)) {|j,r|
    r[j] = special }.map {|e| e.nil? ? vals.shift : e }
end
  # e.g., stuff_special( 'z', [1,4], ["a","b","c"]) => ["a","z","b","c","z"]
```

Comment: Looks promising, but it's missing values. There should be 37 results for the second example, not 18. For example, `["z","z","z"]` is missing, and `["a","a","z"]`.

Comment: Wow, that sure isn't pretty, but it is right! I'll leave this a few more days to see if someone else comes up with a more elegant solution.